# How to pass a value from address bar to a HTML input attribute?

Tags: php, html

My URL is `/mithun/add.php?bc=3`

The "bc" being the attribute name. How can I pass this value so that it shows me the value 3 as input on the screen.

My source code:

```
    <body>
    <h1>Add new product</h1>                
    <form action="add.php" method="post">                   
    Barcode: <input type="text" name="bc" />                
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />    
    </form>         
    </body>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Replace text type with this Barcode: `<input type="text" name="bc" value ="<?php echo $_GET['bc']?>" />` 
You can access it also from url portion like

```
<?php $arr = explode("=",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
echo $arr[1];
 ?>  
<input type="text" name="bc" value ="<?php echo $arr[1];?>" />
```

Comment: **Danger**: This is vulnerable to [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). Never put unescaped, unsanitized user input directly into the page. (And using REQUEST URI instead of $_GET is just silly, it doesn't handle URL escapes or special characters properly)

Answer (score 1):

you can first get the value by `$_GET['bc']` and then echo in the input type  and its always good to see weather the $_GET['bc'] is set or not and escape it  you can do this by

```
<input type="text" name="bc" value ="<?php

 if( isset($_GET['bc']) &&   ctype_digit($_GET['bc'])) 

    echo  $_GET['bc'];
 else
    echo "other default" ; ?> />
```

and if you want to pass value from url use GET method instead

Comment: i have no problem with downvote but i appreciate reason so that i can know my mistake

Comment: Reason is a good thing, but mostly no one give a reason and will just down vote for you without any reason.

Comment: **Danger**: This is vulnerable to [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). Never put unescaped, unsanitized user input directly into the page.

Comment: @Quentin oops .... i made a terrible mistake ... thankyou .. to pointing it out ...thanks a ton

Comment: @Quentin i hope now its fine please take a look ..

Comment: Since the example data consists of a number, checking that the value is a letter probably isn't going to be a good solution. Escape it instead of guessing what suitable validation rules are.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
    <h1>Add new product</h1>                
    <form action="add.php" method="post">                   
    Barcode: <input type="text" name="bc" value="<?php echo $_GET['bc']; ?>" />                
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />    
    </form>         
 </body>
```

Comment: **Danger**: This is vulnerable to [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). Never put unescaped, unsanitized user input directly into the page.